# Stably equivalent bundles and stable homotopy classes of maps

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes, classifying-spaces, stable-homotopy-theory

We know that there is a one-to-one correspondence between isomorphism classes of principal $G$-bundles over a base space $M$ and homotopy classes of maps $M \to BG$, where $BG$ is the classifying space of $G$.

Let us restrict to the case of (real or complex) vector bundles.   What happens to the above correspondence if I consider vector bundles *up to stable equivalence* and *stable* homotopy classes of maps $[M,BG]_*$?  Are there any relationships at all?  I'm hoping that there might again be a one-to-one correspondence, but at the moment I have no insight as to whether the correspondence is even well-formed.

This question arose from some thoughts on how well characteristic classes actually classify vector bundles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Real resp. complex $n$-dimensional vector bundles are classified by homotopy classes of maps $M \to BO(n)$ resp. $M \to BU(n)$. Stable real resp. complex vector bundles are classified by homotopy classes (not stable homotopy classes) of maps $M \to BO$ resp. $M \to BU$, where $O$ is the [stable orthogonal group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stable+orthogonal+group) and $U$ is the [stable unitary group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stable+unitary+group).

This usage of "stable" is not quite the same as the usage in stable homotopy, although they can be related through the unstable and stable [J-homomorphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-homomorphism). In particular, you will sometimes see the homotopy groups $\pi_n(O)$ resp. $\pi_n(U)$ called the "stable homotopy" of the orthogonal resp. unitary groups (e.g. this phrase is used in Bott's classical paper on [Bott periodicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bott_periodicity_theorem)); these groups are *not* stable homotopy groups in the sense of stable homotopy theory.

With regard to characteristic classes, the Stiefel-Whitney and Pontryagin classes are all stable in the sense that they are all pulled back from characteristic classes on $BO$, so  they can only see the stable equivalence class of a vector bundle, and similarly the Chern classes are all pulled back from characteristic classes on $BU$.  The Euler class of an oriented real vector bundle is unstable, so it can tell you, for example, that the tangent bundle to an even-dimensional sphere $S^{2n}$ is nontrivial even though it is stably trivial.

Stable homotopy classes of maps $M \to BO$ resp. $M \to BU$ are the wrong thing to ask for. If I'm not mistaken, this is equivalent to asking for homotopy classes of maps between the [suspension spectra](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/suspension+spectrum) of $M$ and $BO$ resp. $BU$, but taking suspension spectra destroys information about $BO$: it is *already* an [infinite loop space](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/infinite+loop+space) (by Bott periodicity!), hence a [connective spectrum](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/connective+spectrum), and so maps $M \to BO$ resp. $M \to BU$ already factor through the suspension spectrum of $M$. That is, the set of homotopy classes of maps $M \to BO$ resp. $M \to BU$ is already an invariant of the stable homotopy type of $M$. I think when $M$ is connected it can be identified with reduced [real K-theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_K-theory) $\widetilde{KO}^0(M)$ resp. reduced complex K-theory $\widetilde{KU}^0(M)$.

Answer (score 3):

The notion of "vector bundles up to stable equivalence" isn't defined for a general topological group $G$.  Stable equivalence for vector bundles is defined in terms of taking direct sums with trivial bundles, but there is no analogous notion for a general topological group.  So one side of the question is ill-defined.